# How to produce this node graph in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to produce this figure:
[image]

I need help in producing this graph in tikz. The color and shading does not matter.

I can only produce the 3 levels with circle in the second level. But I do not know how to make the level 2 circle disappear and draw a dotted line. Also I do not know how to add edge label.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{comment}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes, backgrounds}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\pagecolor{olive!50!yellow!0!white}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node [circle,draw]{A} [level distance=10mm,sibling distance=25mm]
child { node [circle,draw]{B} [level distance=10mm ,sibling distance=15mm]
child {node [circle,draw]{D}}
}
child {node [circle,draw] {E} [level distance=10mm ,sibling distance=15mm]
child {node [circle,draw] {F}}
child {node [circle,draw]{G}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @CarLaTeX I know how to do this without the 2nd hidden level and produce a tree. But the dotted line and the branch from it really makes me puzzled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the node style `coordinate` for the empty nodes, Name them and use the coordinates to draw the dotted line.

As for the Labels: `edge from parent node[left]{label}`

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every child node/.style={circle,draw}]
 \node [every child node] {A} [level distance=15mm,sibling distance=30mm]
child { node [coordinate] (i) {}
        child {node {B}}
        edge from parent node[left] {1}
}
child {node [coordinate] (j) {} [sibling distance=3.5em,
                                 every child/.style={->}]
       child {node {C} edge from parent node[left] {3}}
       child {node {D} edge from parent node[left] {4}}
       child {node {E} edge from parent node[left] {5}}
       child {node {F} edge from parent node[left] {6}}
       edge from parent node[right] {2}
};
\draw[dotted] (j) +(-15mm,0) -- +(15mm,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, by using the style `every child node` instead of giving the sytle Options `draw, circle` to every node, you can now, easily Change all nodes style whitin the tree, which is quite useful if you decide, for instance, that the nodes should be shaded...

---

EDIT (for the OP)

```
\node [every child node] {A} [level distance=15mm,sibling distance=30mm]
child[level distance=30mm] {node {B}
        edge from parent node[left] {1}
}
```

Comment: thanks. is there a way to make the kinked line 1 to a straight line?

Comment: Yes, but number "1" won't be aligned with "2" then (you can align them, but manually). Just replace the `node[coordinate] (i) {}` and `child{node{B}}` for `node {B}` and give the option `[level distance=30mm]` to the `child` path command before the `node {B}` (the magical number `30` is just two times the "normal" level distance). But, to be honest, I like this layout better.

Comment: but this way B does not end up on the same level of C,D,E,F?

Comment: Not in the same logical level, no. But visually, it will be on the same level.

Comment: but how to make them appear on the same level as in the drawn figure myself?

Comment: @kww, they will appear as in your drawing (the blue one). Do as I said before, compile and see the result.

Comment: in your comment, is it by changing `\node [every child node] {A} [level distance=15mm,sibling distance=30mm]` to `\node [every child node] {A} [level distance=30mm]` and `child { node [coordinate] (i) {}
        child {node {B}}
        edge from parent node[left] {1}
}` to `child{  node {B}
        edge from parent node[left] {1}
}`?

Comment: No, almost that. look the EDIT part of the answer.